# Get injected IOptions<AppSettings>

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to build my first ASP.NET vNext web application and the problem I've faced is that I can't get `IOptions<AppSettings>` injected to my `Startup.Configure()` method. The odd thing is that MVC sample site which was generated by VS2015 does the same steps but the same injecting works! Both projects are run on Desktop CLR and use 1.0.0-beta4 binaries. I have created [gist](https://gist.github.com/lightel/2e5e766e3a03a4c18a4e) with my project's files. I will appreciate any advise or help with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your ConfigureServices method, try adding the following:

`services.AddOptions()`

This registers `OptionsManager<>` which is used to resolve the services of type `IOptions<>`.

Comment: Adding `services.AddOptions()` to ConfigureServices() method helped to resolve this problem. However I don't quite understand why this works in VS2015 sample project w/o adding this line.

Comment: Actually I've found the answer. In the VS2015 sample project the `services.AddMvc()` actually calls `services.AddOptions()`.

Comment: What using statement is needed in the controller to avoid `type or namespace name IOptions<> could not be found` ?

Comment: @schmidlop  `using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;` works